# I cant seem to edit my image's width and height in css

Tags: html, css

So I am using brackets to code and I am very new to programming I put a div element around my image so I could edit it in css but for some reason the width and heights are not changing

```css
h1 {
    width: 300px;
    margin:400px auto;
    color: red;
    font-family:Impact ;
}
.character{
    width:45px; 
    height:45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainc.css">
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            So I am just testing out stuff on here 
        </h1>
        <div class: "character">
        <img src="C:/Users/Nick Malone/Desktop/Downloads/block.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the normal dimensions are 225 by 225

Comment: you aren't targeting your image with a selector.

Comment: How would I do that? Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h1 {
    width: 300px;
    margin:400px auto;
    color: red;
    font-family:Impact ;
}
img{
    width:45px; 
    height:45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainc.css">
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            So I am just testing out stuff on here 
        </h1>
        <div class= "character">
        <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div class: "character">` is a wrong notation to assign a class to a div. Try it as `<div class="character">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your css to target the image. See below.

```
.character img{
    width:45px; 
    height:45px;
}
```

Comment: @nick you need to update your HTML with `<div class="character">` As mentioned in another answer

Comment: As @kkk said, You need to update your div class to `<div class="character"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
. character img{
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the width and the height to the image not the div.

```css
h1 {
    width: 300px;
    margin:400px auto;
    color: red;
    font-family:Impact ;
}
#character{
    width:45px; 
    height:45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainc.css">
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            So I am just testing out stuff on here 
        </h1>
        <div>
        <img src="C:/Users/Nick Malone/Desktop/Downloads/block.jpg" id="character">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```